# Difference between dates in Months and Days

Tags: c#, datetime, interval

I've written a function that returns how many Months and Days are between two dates. I want to respect calendar month boundaries, but I'm ignoring time as it's not relevant for my needs.

I've got the following, but I feel like I'm missing thing I can do to optimize it/refactor it. So I'm looking for additional eyes to help me review this.

```cs
//As opposed to TimeSpan ^_^
public readonly struct CalendarSpan 
{
    public CalendarSpan(int months, int days)
    {
        Months = months;
        Days = days;
    }
    public readonly int Months;
    public readonly int Days;
}

public static CalendarSpan DifferenceInMonthsAndDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    //Ensuring that the larger of two dates is the latter argument 
    if (startDate > endDate)
        return DifferenceInMonthsAndDays(endDate, startDate);

    //Start with getting the difference in months
    var months = 12 * (endDate.Year - startDate.Year) + endDate.Month - startDate.Month;

    int days;
    //Add the difference in months to the smaller of the two dates
    var addedMonths = startDate.AddMonths(months);
    if (addedMonths <= endDate)
        //So long as we can avoid negative numbers, just do the simple math
        days = endDate.Day - addedMonths.Day;
    else
    {
        //Otherwise, backoff by 1 months, and use the built in Subtract logic to get the number of days between the two dates
        months--;
        addedMonths = startDate.AddMonths(months);
        days = endDate.Subtract(addedMonths).Days;
    }

    return new CalendarSpan(months, days);
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have been trying to get unit tests for this, and I honestly don't know why I ever attempted this. It is NOT an easy or straight forward thing to do at all.
*Insert obligatory meme of Homer disappearing into the hedges*

Comment: This will give the same span for some combinations of dates (e.g. May 30 -> Jun 30 and May 31 -> Jun 30 will both give 1 month 0 days because [AddMonths](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=netframework-4.8) will return the last day of the month if the calculated day does not exist).  Is this expected/acceptable behavior?

Comment: You mention `as opposed to timespan`, but you don't justify why.

Comment: Can you add some unit tests to show what output you would expect? For example with `30.01.2019` and `01.12.2019` your solution gives 10 months, 1 day but I could imagine that 10 months and 2 days would be equally likely, depending on where you start.

Comment: @tinstaafl I think that was just a comment about the naming of the struct. As to why not use a TimeSpan the reason is probably because it has no concept of months or years of a difference which makes sense for a accurate and technical result but does not fulfill the need that humans like to think in month differences.

Comment: Is the end date inclusive or exclusive? A simple example: 01.01.2020 - 01.01.2020 should yield 0 or 1 days?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Correct. I'm more interested in the number of Calendar months between two dates than the number of days. I'm using this to determine how much something should charge when it's billed per calendar month for scheduling reasons (not per 30.5 days). But I also need to know the number of days when it's not enough to be a full calendar month.

Comment: @poke Hmm, I've got a bug somewhere then. `30.01.2019` to `01.12.2019` gives the same result as `31.01.2019` to `01.12.2019`

Comment: @dfhwze Yes, that's correct, It should be 0 days since they are the same date, and I'm not concerned with time.

Comment: The example listed by @poke is the same as the problem I described.  Since adding 10 months to January 31 gives November 31, which doesn't exist, the result will be November 30, which is the same date you get when adding 10 months to January 30.

Comment: *“It is NOT an easy or straight forward thing to do at all.”* – Welcome to the world of calendar dates… 

Comment: I've voted to close this because I think it is impossible to comment on the suitability of the code without a better specification.

Comment: Considering the difficulty of dealing with dates, wouldn't it be easier to use something like https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime ?

Answer (score 0):

Last answer deleted (instead of substantially revising).

**Notes** (see comments in code)

1. `CalendarSpan` signed (date1 > date2 => negative span)
2. Extension overload of `DateTime.Add()` taking CalendarSpan argument
3. Unit test approach (see `Main()` which iterates positive and negative differences, using `DateTime` functions to check integrity of results)

`

```
using System;

namespace DateDiff
{
  static class Program
  {
    public readonly struct CalendarSpan 
    {
      public CalendarSpan(int months, int days)
      {
        Months = months;
        Days = days;
      }
      public readonly int Months;
      public readonly int Days;
    }

    //  Maintains sign-consistency, i.e. if l > r returned value components are positive and if l < r negative
    public static CalendarSpan MonthDaysDifference(this DateTime l, DateTime r)
    {
      var mDiff = l.Month - r.Month + 12 * (l.Year - r.Year);

      var dDiff = (l - r.AddMonths(mDiff)).Days;
      if (dDiff == 0 //  no day, the span is a whole number of months
          || l > r && dDiff > 0 //  day and month differences ...
          || l < r && dDiff < 0) //  ... have the same sign
        return new CalendarSpan(mDiff, dDiff);
      //  Signs differ
      var dSign = Math.Sign(dDiff);
      var mSign = Math.Sign(mDiff);
      //  It doesn't matter which sign is which, we adjust months in the correct direction
      mDiff += dSign;
      //  and recalculate days
      return new CalendarSpan(mDiff, (l - r.AddMonths(mDiff)).Days);
    }

    public static DateTime Add(this DateTime dt, CalendarSpan span)
    {
      return dt.AddMonths(span.Months).AddDays(span.Days);
    }

    //  Included to suggest how to test
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      {
        var date1 = new DateTime(2017, 12, 25).AddDays(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
          var date2 = new DateTime(2019, 01, 01).AddDays(j);
          var dateDiff = date1.MonthDaysDifference(date2);
          //var dateDiff2 = MonthDaysDifference(date1,date2);//just checking
          if (date2.Add(dateDiff) != date1)
          {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {date1:yyyy-MM-dd} - {date2:yyyy-MM-dd} = {dateDiff.Months} months + {dateDiff.Days} days");
            Console.WriteLine("Any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
          }
          Console.WriteLine($"{date1:yyyy-MM-dd} - {date2:yyyy-MM-dd} = {dateDiff.Months} months + {dateDiff.Days} days");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```